# Rails - list of years in HAML search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, date

How can I have a search form have a list of years?

Parameters:

- Rails3
- Is not tied to a database object
- Should use current year and have a range of -20 years to current year.
- Should not use a date-picker.  I just want the year.
- Should be in HAML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select_tag "year", options_for_select(((Date.today.year - 20)..Date.today.year).to_a)
```

Comment: I switched to this as it a better, easier to read, DRYER, simpler, shorter solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= select_tag "year", ((Date.today.year-20)..Date.today.year).map{|year| "<option>#{year}</option>"}.join.html_safe %>
```

We worked on this for a bit and (I also use HAML) the answer (I have accepted it) was

```
= select_tag "year", ((Date.today.year-20)..Date.today.year).map{|year| "<option>#{year}</option>".html_safe}
```

Comment: @Michael Durrant, yeap, here was a mistake, but it should work now

Comment: I am still having issues, i think because I am using HAML, as I get

Comment: I see the problem with `html_safe` here.

Comment: @Michael Durrant, Try this: `raw(select_tag "year", ((Date.today.year-20)..Date.today.year).map{|year| "<option>#{year}</option>"}.join)`

Comment: @fl00r..Rails has a method `options_for_select` for doing what you are trying to achieve..just pass the array of values to that method